# jQuery-Mobile Disable Page Dragging & prevent Scroll over Header/Footer

Tags: jquery, ios, css, jquery-mobile

The Scrollbars in my Webapp are supposed to only scroll the "content" part.
But as soon as I scroll to the end or top of the content the scrollbars scroll the header or footer. Also the page gets dragged which looks really ugly.

Here some pictures:

**https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPyrJ.png**

**The header and the footer are fixed in position.**

Header:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
```

Footer:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
```

How can I prevent this behavior?
Thank you.

Comment: what version of jquery mobile are u using?

Comment: I am using version 1.3.1.

Comment: Any Idea? I did not changed anything in CSS besides colors and stuff. Basically in the body there is the **data-role="page"**, in there is the **data-role="header"**, next the **data-role="content"** and finally **data-role="footer"** with **data-role="navbar"**

Comment: happens on all browsers?

Comment: I just tried Google Chrome on my PC, it does not work. But I also tried it on mobile safari (ios) and it did not work :/

Comment: are you sure all tags are closed? js libraries loaded in head? etc...

Comment: Yes. This is bothering me 3 days. I just scripted it again (without my content and my color-design. It does not work. here is the code: http://pastebin.com/5fF9FxPp

Comment: add this in `head` section `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`. `user-scalable=no"` might be the problem

Comment: Still not working.  :/

Comment: Could you post the corresponding source code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/KJaAT/show/ it works fine, the page doesn't drag nor header/footer changes position. scrollbar appears on right side.

Comment: @TolisEmmanouilidis http://pastebin.com/5fF9FxPp

Comment: @Omar Oups, I missed that comment. Thnx :)

Comment: @TolisEmmanouilidis go get some coffee =)

Comment: :D Thank you all for your time. It is weird your jsfiddle is also not working for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: tested on chrome (pc) and safari (iphone).

Comment: Since even your jsfiddle is not working for me , see here:( http://imgur.com/wOb51sC ) I just tried **iScrollview and it worked** (although I had to remove float:left from my content items, but I'll find an other solution for float. Thank you guys for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Had you tried to also include the all three attributes to your header?

- data-position="fixed"
- data-tap-toggle="false"
- data-update-page-padding ="false"

Here is the code:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-update-page-padding ="false"> </div>
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Give an ID to your header. And try to add this script.

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_header").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: false });
});
```

## HTML

```
<div id="my_header" data-role="header" data-theme="b">      
    <h1>Header</h1>        
</div>
```